# using react native picker with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

hi im having troubles with my picker, i need to print a list of options inside my picker but im not able to make it work using hooks, im having troubles with the map function

this is my code

```
   const [vZipCode, setvZipCode] = useState('');
  const [vState, setvState] = useState('Estado');
  const [vCity, setvCity] = useState('Ciudad');
  const [vSuburb, setvSuburb] = useState('Colonia');


const getAddres = ({vZipCode}) => {
axios.post(`http://exitusdesarrollo.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com/AppForceControllers/controllers/GetAddressController.php`, {vZipCode})
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.state);
      console.log(res.data.city);
      console.log(res.data.suburbs);
      setvState(res.data.state);
      setvCity(res.data.city);
      setvSuburb(res.data.suburbs);
    })
}

return (

    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity 
            style={ styles.logout}  
            onPress={() => getAddres({vZipCode})}>  
            <Text style={styles.loginText}>Obtener Ubicacion</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={styles.ocointainer}>
            <View style={styles.pickcontainer}>
            <Picker style={styles.pick} 
                    selectedValue={vSuburb}
                    onValueChange={newvSuburb => setvSuburb(newvSuburb.toUpperCase())}
            >          
            {setvSuburb.map((item,index)=> {
                return <Picker.Item 
                            key={index} 
                            label = {'${item.name}'} 
                            value = {'${item.name}'} />
                }
                )
            }
                </Picker>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.inputIcon}  >
                <Image  source={require('../assets/Flecha.png')}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
```

this is  the array that setvSuburb has

```
suburbs":[{"0":"Burócrata"},{"1":"El Cielo"},{"2":"Privada de Cortez Residencial"},{"3":"La Aurora"},{"4":"Loma Linda"},{"5":"Aeropuerto"},{"6":"Campo de Tiro"}]
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `setvSuburb` isn't an array. It's a function.
2. You are mapping over your function, not your data.
3. You should be using parentheses around your `<Picker.item>`.
4. You initialize `vSuburb` to a string. It should be an empty array.

See if this helps:

```js
{vSuburb.map((item,index) => {
    return (
        <Picker.Item
            key={index} 
            label = {'${item.name}'} 
            value = {'${item.name}'}
        />
    );
}
```

Also this:

```js
const [vSuburb, setvSuburb] = useState([]);
```

Comment: it throws an error when i try to update the state of the array, TypeError, undefined is not a function (near '...vSuburb.map...')

Comment: Try changing it to `{(vSuburb || []).map`. You also need to change this line: `onValueChange={newvSuburb => setvSuburb(newvSuburb.toUpperCase())}` You are replacing the array with a string.

Comment: should i just put  onValueChange={newvSuburb => setvSuburb(newvSuburb)}  ?

Comment: No, use `vSuburb` for your array of data and create a new piece of state for selecting. Maybe call it `pSuburb`.

Comment: something like this? onValueChange={newvSuburb => pSuburb(newvSuburb)}

the screen doesnt show an error anymore when loading but it shows the next warning "Warning: failed prop type: onvalid prop 'value' of type 'array' supplied to 'TextInput' expected 'string', 
and well it keeps crashing when i update the state

Comment: Did you also update this: `selectedValue={pSuburb}`? You also need to do this: `onValueChange={newvSuburb => setpSuburb(newvSuburb)}`. You need to call the function.

Comment: ok i had to update the const to this 
const [vSuburb, setvSuburb, pSuburb, setpSuburb] = useState([]);

and did what you said, it throws me the next error setSuburb is not a function. (In setSuburb(newvSuburb), setpSuburb is undefined

Comment: You need to create two lines: `const [vSuburb, setvSuburb] = useState([]);` and `const [pSuburb, setpSuburb] = useState('MySuburb');`

Comment: yes this almost did it, it doesnt crash anymore, now the only problem is that it prints ${item.name} instead the actual name, but it display the correct number of options

Comment: [pSuburb, setpSuburb] = useState('MySuburb'); its MySuburb right?

Comment: You need to use backticks instead of single quotes. `\`${item.name}\`` instead of `'${item.name}'`. Yes, replace `MySuburb` with `Colonia` or whichever.

Comment: the label says undefined

Comment: i belive thats an error on the api since it doesnt has the value name

Comment: Yes, try this: `${item[index]}`.

Comment: yes, this did it, thanks you so much, srsly man you saved my life

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `<Picker.Item />`.

let say we have this array:

```
const suburbs = [
      {
        "0": 'Burócrata'
      },
      {
        "1": 'El Cielo'
      },
      {
        "2": 'Privada'
      },
    ];
```

we print a list by using map:

```
 <Picker style={styles.pick} 
         selectedValue={vSuburb}
         onValueChange={newvSuburb => setvSuburb(newvSuburb.toUpperCase())}
 >          
 {suburbs.map((item,index)=> {
     return <Picker.Item 
               key={index} 
               label = {'${item[index]}'} 
               value = {'${item[index]}'} />
   }
  )
 }
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: it gives me an error, it says "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near ...setvSuburb.map...)

Comment: for what i know the  {setvSuburb.map((index)=> {  works without hooks, but on hooks it shiuld work diferent

Comment: Maybe your array is empty or try "suburbs.map...."
because setvSuburb is used to set the state.

Comment: you are right, maybe thatss the trouble, when you load the screen setvSuburb is empty, it get values when you star to filling a form, let me put the whole code

Comment: What do you want list it ?

Comment: We use map for listing an array but i see no array

Comment: the array is in the response of the api, in the axios call  setvSuburb(res.data.suburbs) gets the array

Comment: Can you show me the structure of the data in (res.data.suburbs)?

Comment: suburbs":[{"0":"Burócrata"},{"1":"El Cielo"},{"2":"Privada de Cortez Residencial"},{"3":"La Aurora"},{"4":"Loma Linda"},{"5":"Aeropuerto"},{"6":"Campo de Tiro"}]